# loading an external file into a table with hql

Tags: hive

i've got this error :

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 cannot recognize input near 'date'
> 'STRING' ',' in column name or primary key or foreign key

after executing this :

```
CREATE TABLE achat (date STRING,time STRING,city STRING,item STRING ,price FLOAT, mode STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

i want to load a text file into table achat

Comment: `date` is a keyword in hive so you need to wrap it with backtick (`).

Comment: also you need to add the location etc.